`params` should be awaited - NextJs15
I have a get endpoint as follows:
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import connection from '@config/db';

export async function GET(req: Request, context: { params: { providerId: number } }) {
    const providerId = await context.params.providerId;

  // Placeholder for current user ID (replace this with actual user ID from session/auth)
  const currentUserId = 2; // Change to dynamically fetch from your auth system
  ...


It works but I get this error:
Error: Route "/api/appProviders/listProvider/[providerId]" used params.providerId. params should be awaited before using its properties. Learn more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/sync-dynamic-apis
Any idea on how i could get rid of it?
Thank you
I tried various ways but can't seem to find the solution

The page to which you link proposes solutions.  Have you tried any?

Just follow the solution provided by Next https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/sync-dynamic-apis
I have installed the npx package and no more problems.
I had posted this solution a while ago but it was delete by a moderator, not sure why?

Step 1: npx @next/codemod@latest next-async-request-api --force
Step 2: 'On which files or directory should the codemods be applied?': '.'
Also we need to make sure that the function is declared as async, otherwise the changes won't take effect.

first thing your installing packages which giving u error because of override first in cmd type npm -v or npm --version first type in ur project ncu -u which will update all lasted version of ur node modules like package and nextjs to new version below that follow that then in package.json make change
"packageManager": "npm@anyversion", // mention there your npm version example mine "npm@10.9.0"
  "overrides": {
    "react": "$react",
    "react-dom": "$react-dom"
  },
} 

then save it and run npm install why we are doing this means for nextjs 15 and react 19 is in development every time if u want install any package which leads error by this you can now use only npm install which easy and don't give errors
do this and after install
npx @next/codemod@latest next-async-request-api .
then
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import connection from '@config/db';

export async function GET(req: Request, context: { params: Promise<{ providerId: number }> }) {
    const {providerId} = await context.params.providerId;


You should add Promise for a params

This happens in the latest nextjs 15.
Make it first to store await params, then you can retrieve the params from the layout.
example:
export default async function RootLayout({
children, 
params
    }: 
 Readonly<{
      children: React.ReactNode;
      params: { locale: string }
  }>) {
param = await params // {locale: "id"}
const locale = await param.locale // id

hope it helps

I have the same issue.
Or you using turbopack, like that for dev : next dev --turbopack ?
I tried without and the 'error' disappeared.
And of course I've awaited my params like that for exemple :
export default async function Blog({
  params,
}: Readonly<{
  params: Promise<{ lang: Locale }>;
}>) {
  const { lang } = await params;

I haven't found any issue on github about this, I'll think about opening one.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

update
const providerId = await context.params.providerId;

with
const params = await props.params;
const providerId = params.providerId;

You can check nextjs does this in dashboard

You're getting this error because in Next.js 15, params is actually a Promise that needs to be awaited. Here is how you can fix this,
export async function GET(
  req: Request, 
  context: { params: Promise<{ providerId: number }> }
) {
  const providerId = (await context.params).providerId;
}


I got same error, found out you have to await for params, like this
const {slug} = await params;


This should work:
export async function GET(req: Request, { params } : { params: { providerId: number } }) {
   const { providerId } = await params;
....
}

You can make that params part into a type if your going to be reusing that.
